# echo to a file printing extra tabs

Tags: ant

When `echo`ing to a file. `echo` is printing extra tabs before what is printed.

I do not want these tabs there, why is `ant` doing this and how do i prevent?

**Only using `ant` and/or `ant-contrib`. Nothing else.**

```
<target 
    name="doThis">
    <delete 
        file="${PATH}/install.bat" 
        failonerror="true">
    </delete>

    <touch file="${PATH}/install.bat"></touch>

    <echo
        file="${PATH}/install.bat"
        level="verbose"
        append="true"
        message="if exist preinstall.bat call preinstall.bat${line.separator}">
    </echo>

    <foreach 
        trim="true"
        target="printStuff"
        param="stuffName">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/stuff/"></fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target 
    name="printStuff">
    <basename file="${stuffName}" property="stuffNameSmall"/>
    <echo
        file="${PATH}/install.bat"
        append="true"
        level="verbose"
        message="${stuffNameSmall}${line.separator}">
    </echo>
</target>
```

---

Example of output that is being printed currently:

```
<tab><tab>filename
<tab><tab>filename
<tab><tab>filename
```

Comment: I recently did the same thing and did not notice that behaviour. what exactly is the content of ${line.separator}?

Comment: Removing the `${line.separator}` i am still seeing tabs being generated. I also tried using the `&#xD` and `&#xA`. And was still seeing tabs. It is not hurting the functionality of what is generated, it is just cosmetically bugging me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch: you have 2 tab chars inside the <echo ...> </echo> xml element...

Try:

```
<echo
    file="${PATH}/install.bat"
    append="true"
    level="verbose"
    message="${stuffNameSmall}${line.separator}" />
```

The 'echo' task will print out the 'message' attribute value, as well as everything inside the nested text node. So best to always close the tag immediately if you don't need to printout extra stuff (like multi-line ASCII art, oh yeah!).

Comment: Will try this as soon as i get the chance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting the ANT echo task, I'd suggest using [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to generate the batch script.

The following example is slightly more complex, because I'm using [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download build dependencies.

### Project structure

```
$ tree
.
|-- build.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- stuff
    |-- script1
    |-- script2
    `-- script3

1 directory, 5 files
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="generate-script" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="init">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="build"/>

        <mkdir dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="generate-script" depends="init">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <fileset id="files" dir="stuff"/> 

        <groovy>
        def batchScript = new File("build/install.bat")

        batchScript.withWriter() { writer ->
            writer.println "if exist preinstall.bat call preinstall.bat"

            project.references.files.each {
                def stuffFile = new File(it.toString())

                writer.println stuffFile.name 
            }
        }
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="build" description="ANT tasks"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Build dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="1.8.2" conf="build->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

## Update

This wasn't meant to be a justification for using ivy, but anything available from Maven Central could be installed.

For example [ant-contrib](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cant-contrib%7Cant-contrib%7C1.0b3%7Cjar):

```
  <dependency org="ant-contrib" name="ant-contrib" rev="1.0b3"/>
```

Comment: I can only use `ant` or `ant-contrib`. Anything else just adds a lot of dependencies that i do not want to worry about.

Comment: @prolink007 that is the whole point of using ivy. Let it download the dependencies for you.

Comment: I am talking about dependencies that are neccessary for the script to even run. I do not want the person using my ant script to have to download anything but `ant` and `ant-contrib` for this to work. Not talking about build dependencies, environment dependencies.

Comment: Yeah..... swap the ant-contrib.jar with the ivy.jar and you could use ivy to auto-install ant contrib.